# Jquery time difference in hours from two fields ( AM/PM Format)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having two fields in my form where users select  input time (start_time, end_time) I would like to calculate time duration between these two time field.

eg: start_time = 6:00 AM,  end_time= 3:00 PM,  duration = 7

start_time and end_time, both are in AM/PM Format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function. Working with your time format.

```js
    $('.btn_duration').on("click", function(){
       duration();
    })

    function duration() {
      var _starttime = $('#start_time').val();
      var _endtime = $('#end_time').val();

      //divide AM/PM from time
      var _split_starttime = _starttime.split(" ");
      var _split_endtime = _endtime.split(" ");

      //check if start time is bigger than end time
      if (_split_starttime[1] == "PM") {
        alert("start time can't be bigger than end time.");
        return false;
      }
      else {
        var _start_timenumber = _split_starttime[0].split(".");
        var _end_timenumber = _split_endtime[0].split(".");

        //start time hour & minute
        var _start_hour = parseInt(_start_timenumber[0]); 
        var _start_min = parseInt(_start_timenumber[1]); 

        //end time hour & minute
        var _end_hour = parseInt(_end_timenumber[0]); 
        var _end_min = parseInt(_end_timenumber[1]); 

        //get hour duration
        var _hour_format = 0;
        if (_split_endtime[1] == "PM") {
          if(_end_hour == 12){
            _end_hour = 0;
          }
          _hour_format = _end_hour + 12;
        }
        else{
          _hour_format = _end_hour;
        }
        var _duration_hour = _hour_format - _start_hour;

        //calculate minutes
        var _remained_min = Math.abs(_start_min - _end_min);;

        //final result
        var _final_duration = _duration_hour + "Hour " + _remained_min + "Minutes";
        $('#result').val(_final_duration);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="text" id="start_time" value="6.10 AM">
  <input type="text" id="end_time" value="2.45 PM">
  <input type="text" id="result" value="">
  <button class="btn_duration">Calculate</button>
```